# Capturing Gradle output in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Unity version 2021.3.1f1.
Where can I find Gradle output?
I looked in `Logs`, under `Library`, and, since I am running on a MAC, under `$HOME/Library/Logs/Unity`, but I can't find any Gradle build output.
I did see some output that describe merging of AndroidManifest.xml, but there should be much more information that describes the build.